# sm-select not working for formArray

Tags: angular

I am using the ng-semantic select plugin in my angular 2 app.

[ng-semantic](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/ngSemantic)

I have the following html script

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(testForm.value)">
<div fomArrayName="testAttributes">
<div [formGroupName]="0">
<sm-select
    [options]="{direction: 'downward'}" 
    placeholder="Attributes" 
    [formControl]="attributeMaster"
    (onChange)="updateModel($event);"
    class="fluid">
    <option *ngFor="let item of selectAttributes" [value]="item.label">
        <span [innerHTML]="item.value.displayName"></span>
</sm-select>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

And in my component

```
public buildForm(): void {
    this.testForm = this._fb.group({
        testAttributes: this._fb.array([])
    });
    this.loadFormArray();
}

public loadFormArray(): void {
    this.attributesFromServer.forEach(attribute => {
        (<FormArray>this.testForm.controls["testAttributes"]).push(this.createArrayData(attribute))
    })
}

public createArrayData(attribute: Attribute) {
    return this._fb.group({
        attributeMaster: [attribute.attributeMaster, <any>Validators.required]
    })
}
```

When i run the application, i am getting the following error,

> Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

When i change the html script to

```
<sm-select
    [options]="{direction: 'downward'}" 
    placeholder="Attributes" 
        formControlName="attributeMaster"
    (onChange)="updateModel($event);"
    class="fluid">
    <option *ngFor="let item of selectAttributes" [value]="item.label">
        <span [innerHTML]="item.value.displayName"></span>
</sm-select>
```

Iam getting the following error,

> No value accessor for form control with path: 'testAttributes -> 0 ->
>   attributeMaster

And the error point to the line where we set the formControl attribute for sm-select above. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. My bad i didn't notice the [control] attribute for sm-select in the demo page before.

[sm-select demo](https://ng-semantic.herokuapp.com/#/elements/select)

My Apologies. I changed `[formControl]` to `[control]` and it's working now.